# Change Label color of status bar in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uistatusbar

In iPhone we have a `UIStatusBar` which shows the time. Does anybody know how I can change its `textcolor`?

Below is the code changing style, but can we change THE label's color?

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should insert your line of code inside `AppDelegate`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

and than also set a value for the statusbar inside info.plist like this

[image]